# Use of Single and Double Quotes

Tags: quotation-marks

1. When should we use single and double quotation marks?
2. Should full stop and other exclamation mark be inside or outside quotes?

Thanks,
Avadhut

Comment: Depends on which church of punctuation you worship in.  But generally single quotes are reserved for quotations inside quotations:  "This is a quote which contains 'This quotation'."

Comment: This is a matter of style; there is no single "correct" way. Adhere to the guidance of your editor or style guide, and be consistent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should single quotes be used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31420/when-should-single-quotes-be-used)

Answer (score 2):

(1) For simple quotations, Americans use double quotes and Brits use single:

- She said, "No." (U.S.)
- She said, 'No.' (U.K.)

For quotations within quotations, the usage switches:

- She said, "Bob said, 'No way.' " (U.S.)
- She said, 'Bob said, "No way." ' (U.K.)

(2) If the punctuation mark is part of the quoted text, it goes inside. And if the quotation ends the sentence, no punctuation mark follows:

- She said, "No way!" (U.S.)
- She said, 'No way!' (U.K.)

If the punctuation mark is NOT part of the quoted text, it goes outside, except for full stops (periods) and commas in American writing:

- I couldn't believe she said "No"! (U.S.)
- I couldn't believe she said 'No'! (U.K.)
- In Spanish, "cat" is "gato." (U.S.)
- In Spanish, 'cat' is 'gato'. (U.K.)
- "Hello," she said. (U.S.)
- 'Hello', she said. (U.K.)