# single quote and double quote

Tags: quotes

I have a question around the use of single and double quote. To the best of my knowledge, single quote is used to invite attention to a specific word in a sentence or to enclose double quotes within a sentence, whereas double quote is used to set off a direct speech from the sentence.

Is my understand right?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you asking about BrE or AmE?  Nonetheless, you should be able to find an answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/whats-the-difference-between-using-single-and-double-quotation-marks-inverted-c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using single and double quotation marks/inverted commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/whats-the-difference-between-using-single-and-double-quotation-marks-inverted-c)