# Double Quotes Within Double Quotes

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I can't find anything that addresses how to quote a sentence that contains a word in double quotes. Here's the quote (also a sentence fragment).
**and a catchall “other” bin.**
Also, is it proper to use an ellipsis to precede a sentence fragment when quoting a fragment?

Comment: Both of these seem to be a question of style rather than language rules.

Comment: In my experience, a common convention is to alternate double-quotes and single quotes at each nesting level - "First level 'second level "third level" ' "

Comment: American English style: *The report identified five UFO categories: airborne clutter, natural atmospheric phenomena, USG or U.S. industry developmental programs, foreign adversary systems, and “a catchall ‘other’ bin.”*

Comment: Sensibly substituting single inverted commas for double inverted commas should not present an issue except when discussing such punctuation.

Comment: @KillingTime Style questions about how to punctuate things is very much on topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using single and double quotation marks/inverted commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/whats-the-difference-between-using-single-and-double-quotation-marks-inverted-c) The question on the dupe is not well-worded, but the answers go above and beyond the issues expressed here.