# Quotation Marks After "the words..."

Tags: quotation-marks

Can't find this after googling thirty minutes.

In the following sentence, should I use quotation marks or not?

- James used the words stupid, dumb, and fidiotic in his briefing.
- James used the words 'stupid,' 'dumb,' and 'fidiotic' his briefing.

Comment: _Fidiotic_? A word referred to as a word and not part of the sentence is usually set off by inverted commas or italics.

Comment: Any good style guide should cover this, e.g. [APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/italics-quotations/quotation-marks), [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-q); some may recommend single or double quotes or italics. Where to put the commas is another question.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/whats-the-difference-between-using-single-and-double-quotation-marks-inverted-c) has lots of good advice.

Comment: You can ditch the quotation marks and use italics instead.